# How to know what type of object the client is putting in a Param?

Tags: java, spring

I have an endpoint that allows you to filter between a list of employees, but it only works with Strings, when i try to filter for "Salary" it doesnt take count of the Salary defined in the Class because is a Double

i tried passing an "Object" but it ignore doubles anyway, only read the Strings

```
    public Map<String, Empleado> getEmpleadosByParam(@RequestParam (required = false) Map<String, Object> allParams){
        return empleadoService.findByParam(allParams);
    }


    @Query("{ '?0' : { $eq: ?1 } }")
    List<Empleado> searchByParam(String key, Object value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic request params will always be String or String/String or Array of String. You can specify a request Class object

```
private String lastName;
private long idNum;
private double salary;
```

for instance, if your param names are well defined, and convert it to a map in the controller.